# In R how to merge data in ranges, or how to use the %in% operator if the range are in strings "1:x"

Tags: merge, label, range

I would like to label my numeric data. The idea is easy, if the value of my data is in the range of 10:20 then it belongs to group 1 if the value is in the range (21,25:30) then it belongs to group 2 etc. The labels are defined in an excel which I import. My problem is that I can not build the ranges from the data because they are strings.

Here is an example:

Create data (I read it from excel but this is the structure)

`labels <- data.frame(group = 1:3, codes = c("10:20", "21,30:40", "25:26"))`

`data<-data.frame(value = c(10,25,36,21,12))`

Ideally, I would like to do something like
"merge(data,labels,by.x = value,by.y = codes)"

However, I don't know if it is possible,

I also tried

```
data$group<- ifelse(data$value %in% labels$codes[1], "group1",
                    ifelse(data$value %in% labels$codes[2], "group2",
                           ifelse(data$value %in% labels$codes[3], "group3","else")))
```

However, R does not read labels$codes[1] as a range of numbers; the only group created is "else".

My goal would be a table like

```
want <- data.frame(group=c(1,3,2,2,1), 
                     value = c(10,25,36,21,12))
```

Does anyone have an idea? Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 0):

A friendly colleague could help me with this question

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

make_intvec <- function(x, sep1, sep2) {
  y <- str_split_1(x, sep1)
  z <- str_split(y, sep2)
  l <- lapply(z, function(v) {
         w <- unlist(v)
         seq(w[1], ifelse(length(w) == 2, w[2], w[1]))
       })
  unlist(l)
}

labels <- data.frame(group = 1:3, codes = c("10:20", "21,30:40", "25:26"))
data <- data.frame(value = c(10,25,36,21,12))

labels_long <- labels %>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(codes_int = list(make_intvec(codes, ",", ":"))) %>%
  unnest(codes_int)

want <- data %>%
  left_join(labels_long, by = join_by(value == codes_int))
```